# Explore finished theories in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I want to see the definitions in the vector spaces theory file of the Isabelle/HOL distribution. [This thread](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2009-November/msg00060.html) of the Isabelle's mailing list explains how to do so with the command: `isabelle make HOL-Base`.

I am working under Windows 10. I guess the above command is meant for Linux. How can I get the same effect in my system?

Comment: Try to start Isabelle from the command line with `isabelle jedit -l Pure` (this will probably look a little bit different under Windows). Now Isabelle/Pure is used as the base image instead of Isabelle/HOL. Next load the theory file you want to check from the Isabelle installation directory (HOL stuff is under `<isabelle-dir>/src/HOL`)

Comment: command-line tools are invoked through Isabelle2018\Cygwin-Terminal.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start Isabelle from the command line with `isabelle jedit -l Pure` (command-line tools are invoked through `Isabelle2018\Cygwin-Terminal.bat` under Windows). Now Isabelle/Pure is used as the base image instead of Isabelle/HOL. Next load the theory file you want to check from the Isabelle installation directory (HOL stuff is under `<isabelle-dir>/src/HOL`)